# Google Scripts: Using setFireEventsForInvalid with DateBox

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am completely new to writing scripts. I am using Google Ui Apps and I am trying to get a handler to fire for a DateBox if an invalid date is entered so a message will appear, but I can not get it to work.
This is part of my code:

```
var grd = app.getElementById('GRDprojDates');
grd.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Project Start Date').setStyleAttributes(styleLabel2));
grd.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Project End Date').setStyleAttributes(styleLabel2));

grd.setWidget(0, 1, app.createDateBox().setId('DateProjStart')
                                       .setName('DateProjStart')
                                       .setStyleAttributes(styleTBox3)
                                       .setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.YEAR_MONTH_ABBR_DAY));
grd.setWidget(1, 1, app.createDateBox().setId('DateProjEnd')
                                       .setName('DateProjEnd')
                                       .setStyleAttributes(styleTBox3)
                                       .setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.YEAR_MONTH_ABBR_DAY));

var hndDateValid = app.createServerHandler('DateVailidation').addCallbackElement(app.getElementById('DateProjStart'))
                                                             .addCallbackElement(app.getElementById('DateProjEnd'))

app.getElementById('DateProjStart').setFireEventsForInvalid(true).addValueChangeHandler(hndDateValid); 
app.getElementById('DateProjEnd').setFireEventsForInvalid(true).addValueChangeHandler(hndDateValid);
```

The function the handler calls is similar to this.

```
function DateVailidation(e)
{
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var dateStart = e.parameter.DateProjStart;
  var dateEnd = e.parameter.DateProjEnd;

  if (dateStart == null) 
  {app.add(app.createLabel("Enter Valid Date"));}

  return app;
}
```

The handler doesn't seem to fire even if I put only text in the datebox.

Answer (score 0):

It seems logical that the function `DateVailidation(e)` is never called since you have a validation on the date widgets that is there to prevent firing when the date is not valid (that's how you get the red color in the date widget to tell you date is not valid.

What are you really hoping to happen ? Why would the client validation not be sufficient ?

If you really want to trigger the server validation, [here is a test code](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyWNauWkeT2DwWVsLLCSDnm8RNmB8p65j29abYMiDJbDlrH_Miz/exec) that does and shows the results to help you to see what happens.(click the labels to fire the handler)

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var grd = app.createGrid(2,2)
  grd.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Project Start Date'));
  grd.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Project End Date'));
  var start = app.createDateBox().setId('DateProjStart').setName('DateProjStart').setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.YEAR_MONTH_ABBR_DAY);
  var end = app.createDateBox().setId('DateProjEnd').setName('DateProjEnd').setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.YEAR_MONTH_ABBR_DAY);
  grd.setWidget(0, 1, start)
  grd.setWidget(1, 1, end)

  var hndDateValid = app.createServerHandler('DateValidation').addCallbackElement(grd);

  var mainHandler = app.createServerHandler('DateValidation').addCallbackElement(grd);
  grd.addClickHandler(mainHandler);

  start.setFireEventsForInvalid(true).addValueChangeHandler(hndDateValid); 
  end.setFireEventsForInvalid(true).addValueChangeHandler(hndDateValid); 
  app.add(grd);
  return app;
}

function DateValidation(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var dateStart = e.parameter.DateProjStart;
  var dateEnd = e.parameter.DateProjEnd;
  app.add(app.createLabel("Enter Valid Date  ("+e.parameter.DateProjStart+')  ('+e.parameter.DateProjEnd+')'));
  return app;
}
```

[image]